# What kind of plant is this

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowers

I have this plant in my living room, but I don't know what kind of plant it is. I have had this one for 3 years, and it's the first time it has bloomed.
Could you help me identify it and give me some advice on how to encourage it bloom more.
I haven't changed anything in the way I take care of it. I've been keeping it in the same place and watering it with tap water.[image][image][image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the well-known hard to kill [Snake Plant](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/snake-plant/snake-plant-care.htm).

> [..]sturdy, sword-shaped leaves, snake plant is a toughie that thrives with neglect. In fact, too much attention will harm this hard to kill plant. The only real danger is too much moisture, which will rot the plant quickly. Water only when the soil is dry by pouring water around the inner edge of pot to keep the base of the plant dry.

It is a kind of [Sansevieria *(Genus)*(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sansevieria), maybe [***Sansevieria Trifasciata***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sansevieria_trifasciata)

Yours is really beautiful. I never saw it blossom before...

Comment: No kidding, you must be doing something right! Of all the times I have seen this plant in offices, homes and restaurants, I never saw one with flowers on it (and that includes artificial ones too, ... which are often very reliable bloomers)